# Unlink Square Enix ID from PSN account

Tags: ps4, psn, final-fantasy-14

I want to try Final Fantasy XIV Online before buying it. So I downloaded the FFXIV free trial available on the PS Store for my PS4.

When I installed and tried to play the game, I linked my PSN account to the wrong Square Enix ID. Now I can't seem to to unlink them to link again with the correct Square Enix ID.

I have already contacted Square Enix NA, Square Enix Eu, PlayStation Support... but none of them could help me.

Has anyone did the same mistake? Is there any way to unlink this accounts?

Comment: There is a [form](https://support.na.square-enix.com/contact.php?id=5382&la=1&daxx=3) you can fill out to unlink your PSN account with the SEN account, but it does say it may take up to 2 weeks

Comment: Does Europe support has this form? last time I contacted Square NA they said my account was from Europe and couldn't do anything.

Comment: Just found it: https://support.eu.square-enix.com/contact.php?id=5383&la=2&daxx=3. Will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried to enter account at Square Enix webpage under Your ID and ask for password recovery with a suggestion of a new e-mail?
Another thought is to create a new account with this ID if for some reason they have connected You to a non-existing one or to simply create a new account and bind it with your PSN.

If You’re from those players who create new acc on PSN to get free PS+ for two weeks and/or do not care about Your trophies – simply delete this account and make a new one.

***Don't forget to delete all data about credit cards and other payment IDs until You solve this problem.***